# Creating a circle with 4 segments using canvas in android with rotation

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-graphics

I need to create a segmented circle with four random colours like this:

http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/39.png. "4segments in a circle"

I have made the following code on referring to android documentation about using canvas.drawArc() but it dosent work as per my expectations as its showing only one segment.

```
           Bitmap bitMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    bitMap = bitMap.copy(bitMap.getConfig(), true);
    // Construct a canvas with the specified bitmap to draw into
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitMap);
    // Create a new paint with default settings.
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    // smooths out the edges of what is being drawn
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    // set color
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    paint.setStrokeWidth(4.5f);


    RectF oval = new RectF(200F, 200F, 450F, 450F);

    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawArc(oval, 0F, 90F, true, paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    canvas.drawArc(oval, 90F, 90F, true, paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);

    canvas.drawArc(oval, 180F, 90F, true, paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    canvas.drawArc(oval, 270F, 90F, true, paint);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitMap);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arc angles are wrong. See drawArc [Canvas reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawArc(android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint)), the angle arguments are like this:

- startAngle - Starting angle (in degrees) where the arc begins
- sweepAngle - Sweep angle (in degrees) measured clockwise

Your last arc is covering all the previous ones. You should do something like (Kotlin code below):

```
private val oval = RectF(200F, 200F, 450F, 450F)

private val paint = Paint()

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
  paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL

  paint.color = Color.BLACK
  canvas.drawArc(oval, 0F, 90F, true, paint)
  paint.color = Color.BLUE
  canvas.drawArc(oval, 90F, 90F, true, paint)
  paint.color = Color.RED
  canvas.drawArc(oval, 180F, 90F, true, paint)
  paint.color = Color.GREEN
  canvas.drawArc(oval, 270F, 90F, true, paint)
}
```

Will draw something like:

[image: Sample output]

Java version:

```
  private RectF oval = new RectF(0F,0F,100F,100F);

  private Paint paint = new Paint();

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawArc(oval, 0F, 90F, true, paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawArc(oval, 90F, 1800F, true, paint)
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawArc(oval, 0F, 190F, true, paint)
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    canvas.drawArc(oval, 270F, 360F, true, paint)
  }
```

Comment: I have edited my question with your code,its still showing no result.

Comment: You also need to properly specify your RectF, the correct corners in your case are (0,0) and (100,100). Try `new RectF(0, 0, 100, 100)`.

Comment: @ShubhamTunwal In my sample, the canvas is drawing the rectangle starting at 200,200 coordinates. You should adjust them to something like: `private RectF oval = new RectF(20F,20F,40F,40F);`. Also please do not remove the comments, if you leave them other users will be able to follow what was happening.

Comment: @ThomasLeyk Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Can you please also help in rotating this graphic?I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @ShubhamTunwal Please instead of reusing the question, just create another one. We need to help others too. A simple `canvas.rotate(90);` should rotate the image. Or if you need to create the segments in different way just explain in another question what you need and we will gladly help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @dan. I'll draft a fresh question for that.

Comment: @ShubhamTunwal Np, maybe we will meet there too :)